# Drawing blocks with hatch pattern border in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate a block diagram like the one shown on this picture:
[image]

I'm new to latex and the way I created a single block was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spherebrown}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.9059,0.9059,0.5647)
    }
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spheregreen}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(0.7980,0.9686,0.9255);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.2412,0.3941,0.0392)
    }
    \tikzstyle{block_1} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=30mm,minimum height = 10mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=2pt,gray,shading=spherebrown]
    \tikzstyle{block_2} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=32mm,minimum height = 12mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=1pt,gray,pattern=north west lines]
    \tikzstyle{block_3} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=32mm,minimum height = 12mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=1pt,gray,shading=spheregreen]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (0,0)[block_3]{};
        \node (B) at (0,0)[block_2]{};
        \node (C) at (0,0)[block_1,text width=28mm,font=\bfseries\scriptsize,align=center]{\sffamily\textcolor{black}{NOSILAC\\DSS AD9833}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Primjer jednog komunikacijskog sistema sa ARM Cortex M3 MCU i DDS-om}
    \label{slika:6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

But it seems to me that I'm going wrong somewhere because this looks like too much work for a single block, so is there an easier way to create something like this?

Comment: You can use `pic` to make the construct reusable or you can dig into `\pgfdeclareshape` to define a new node shape with the desired properties, but that's almost never necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Instead of `preactions` and `postactions`, this solution uses only `preactions` and a `path picture`. A first preaction to drawn the colored background followed by a second preactions which draws the pattern (remember that preactions are applied in order). After that a `path picture` (which survives to all fillings) is used to draw the inner background. In this case there is no problems with scale factors which change coordinate system (see original code).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, patterns, positioning}

    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spherebrown}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.9059,0.9059,0.5647)
    }
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spheregreen}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(0.7980,0.9686,0.9255);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.2412,0.3941,0.0392)
    }

\tikzset{
    myblock/.style={
        draw, rectangle, minimum width=30mm, minimum height=10mm,
        line width=.5pt, rounded corners=2pt, gray, text width=28mm,
        font=\bfseries\scriptsize\sffamily, align=center, text=black,
        preaction={shading=spheregreen},
        preaction={pattern=north west lines},
        path picture={\draw[rounded corners=2pt, gray, shading=spherebrown] ([shift={(1mm,-1mm)}]path picture bounding box.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}]path picture bounding box.south east);},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [myblock] (A) {NOSILAC\\DSS AD9833};
    \node [myblock, above right=5mm and -5mm of A] {NOSILAC\\DSS AD9833};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original answer**

This is work in progres. Present solution only works for a node at origin.

`preactions` and `postactions` can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, patterns}

    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spherebrown}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.9059,0.9059,0.5647)
    }
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{spheregreen}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(0.7980,0.9686,0.9255);
        rgb(1.5cm)=(0.2412,0.3941,0.0392)
    }

\tikzset{
    myblock/.style={
        draw, rectangle, minimum width=30mm, minimum height=10mm,
        line width=.5pt, rounded corners=2pt, gray, text width=28mm,
        font=\bfseries\scriptsize\sffamily, align=center, text=black,
        preaction={shading=spheregreen},
        postaction={pattern=north west lines},
        postaction={draw, shading=spherebrown, transform canvas={xscale=.9, yscale=.8}},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [myblock] {NOSILAC\\DSS AD9833};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why it doesn't work? I understand that `transform canvas={xscale=..., yscale=...}` applied in last `postaction` to fill the "inner rectangle" also changes the coordinate system applied.

Comment: Yeah this looks much better and cleaner, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @hasanfefer My solution just works for one node at origin. As soon as you place it on another position, inner part moves from center. Let me do some more work until accept it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I noticed as well so I continued doing it my way, but if you manage to finish it, it would  be nice to see how you solved it so I could learn for  future projects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hasanfefer I've found another solution, try it and tell if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

One more possible solution, which use:

- Ti*k*Z libraries `arrows.meta` for arrows, `fit` for nesting inner node, `patterns.meta` for patterns in the outer node, `positioning` for positioning of nodes and `shadows` for shading of nodes.
- Node with `box` style is composed from two nodes: outers with shading of selected color and patterns, and inner one which is shaded yellow and contain text of composed node.
- Instruction `preaction` for shadowing outer node shape.
- Instruction `postaction` for drawing patterns in outer node.
- Instruction `postaction` for drawing outer node border.
- Instruction `append after command` by which is inserted inner node  by using `fit` library.
- In inner node instruction `label` for write node content (text).

Resulted node style (according to my opinion) gives a wee bit nicer result, since patterns not protrude (anymore) in anode borders. Its style definition is:

```
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, very thin, rounded corners=2pt,
                 minimum height=10mm, text width=28mm,
                 node contents={},
    preaction={upper left=#1!10, lower right=#1!90},
    postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt}, line width=0.2pt]}},
    postaction={draw=gray, thick},
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
        node [draw=gray, thick, rounded corners=2pt,
              upper left=yellow!10, lower right=yellow!90,
              inner sep=-1mm, fit=(\LN),
              label={[align=center, font=\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily]center:#2},
              ] {} } }
```

An example of image with use of the proposed `box` style for nodes is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                patterns.meta, positioning,
                shadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 1mm and 6mm,
arr/.style      = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},semithick},
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, very thin, rounded corners=2pt,
                 minimum height=10mm, text width=28mm,
                 node contents={},
    preaction={upper left=#1!10, lower right=#1!90},
    postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt}, line width=0.2pt]}},
    postaction={draw=gray, thick},
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
        node [draw=gray, thick, rounded corners=2pt,
              upper left=yellow!10, lower right=yellow!90,
              inner sep=-1mm, fit=(\LN),
              label={[align=center, font=\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily]center:#2},
              ] {} } }      
                 ]
\node (n1) [box=teal/NOSILAC\\DSS AD9833];
\node (n2) [below right=of n1,    
            box=brown/BJT\\MODULATOR];
\node (n3) [below  left=of n2,
            box=purple/SIGNAL PORUKE\\DSS AD9833];
\draw[arr]   (n1) -| (n2);
\draw[arr]   (n3) -| (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]